# Render watermark in play framework 1.2.x pdf

Tags: pdf-generation, playframework-1.x, watermark

Im using Play framework 1.2.x and PDF moudle 0.9. I would like to render watermark in my generated PDF. I got some information through iText while google it, but not for Play framework. Though Play framework uses iText in lower layers I didn't get any information to configure it. Please help me

**UPDATE:** Im able to achieve this via specifying background image for the body tag

`<body style="background-image:url(/resources/img/draft_watermark.jpg)">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im able to achieve this via specifying background image for the body tag

`<body style="background-image:url(/resources/img/draft_watermark.jpg)">`